# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

Tags: ajax, datatables

i got this error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qm0O.png)

i was trying to get a value from an ajax call, and then i append that value to a datatable but that error shows up

this is my html for the table

```
<table id="tablelaporan" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama Sales</th>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Total Sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

below is my full code for that call

```
function load_data() {
            var bulan = $('#inputbulan').val();
            var tahun = $('#inputtahun').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "services/gettargetsales.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    bulan: bulan,
                    tahun: tahun
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#tablelaporan tbody').html('');
                    $('#tablelaporan').dataTable().fnClearTable();
                    $('#tablelaporan').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    var co = 1;
                    html = "";
                    var i;
                    data.forEach(function(line) {
                        var row = $("<tr></tr>");
                        var col1 = $("<td>" + co + "</td>");
                        var col2 = $("<td>" + line['nama'] + "</td>");
                        var col3 = $("<td>" + line['target'].toLocaleString() + "</td>");
                        stats = 'Sudah Terpenuhi';
                        if (line['status'] == 0) {
                            stats = 'Belum Terpenuhi';
                        }
                        var col4 = $("<td>" + stats + "</td>");
                        col1.appendTo(row);
                        col2.appendTo(row);
                        col3.appendTo(row);
                        col4.appendTo(row);


                        var id_sales = line['id_sales'];
                        var penjualan = 0;

                        // console.log(id_sales);
                        var testing=0;
                        console.log("1:"+testing);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "services/get_penjualan_bulan.php",
                            method: "GET",
                            data: {
                                bulan: bulan,
                                tahun: tahun,
                                id_sales: id_sales
                            },
                            success: function(data2) {
                                penjualan = data2[0]['total'];
                                testing=data2[0]['total'];
                                console.log("2:"+testing);
                                if (data2[0]['total'] == null) {
                                    penjualan = "0";
                                }
                                var col5 = $("<td>" + penjualan + "</td>");
                                col5.appendTo(row);
                            },
                            error: function(data2) {
                                console.log(data2)
                            }
                        });
                        console.log("1:"+testing);

                        // console.log(penjualan)
                        co++;
                        $("#tablelaporan tbody").append(row);
                        html += row;

                    })
                    $('#tablelaporan').DataTable({
                        dom: 'lrtip',
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "scrollX": true
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

the value in the table shows up but i got that error, and when i tried to remove the nested ajax and fill the col5 with 0 it works, anybody know what's happening here and how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of using jQuery Ajax to reload your data, use the Ajax function that comes with DataTables https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have it figured out by adding async:false to the second ajax like so:

```
                         $.ajax({
                            url: "services/get_penjualan_bulan.php",
                            method: "GET",
                            data: {
                                bulan: bulan,
                                tahun: tahun,
                                id_sales: id_sales
                            },
                            async: false, //<-----this is the solution
                            success: function(data2) {
                                penjualan = data2[0]['total'];
                                testing=data2[0]['total'];
                                console.log("2:"+testing);
                                if (data2[0]['total'] == null) {
                                    penjualan = "0";
                                }
                                var col5 = $("<td>" + penjualan + "</td>");
                                col5.appendTo(row);
                            },
                            error: function(data2) {
                                console.log(data2)
                            }
                        });
```

i read this solution isn't really recommended, but it works